# Lifetime of variables created when assigning to something that looks like a tuple

Tags: python, variables, tuples

There is this code:

```
>>> (a, b) = (2, 3)
>>> a
2
>>> b
3
```

Why variables **a** and **b** are alive after tuple creation? I mean that here:

```
(a, b) = (2, 3)
```

is created some tuple and this tuple is not assigned to any variable so garbage collector should immediately destroy this tuple after this line.

Variables **a** and **b** are only references by this tuple - so if this tuple **(a, b)** is destroyed then variables **a** and **b** should be only destroyed also.

So why these variables still exist after definition of tuple?

Comment: As the answers have shown already, `(a, b)` only looks like tuple syntax, thus I changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parser doesn't see `(a, b)` as a tuple, although it does do tuple unpacking for you. Thus, there is no tuple to create, let alone destroy. Instead, python sees this as two separate variables `a` and `b`.

You can see this if you were to disassemble the compiled bytecode for the statement:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     (a, b) = (2, 3)
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((2, 3))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The constant `(2, 3)` is unpacked, then stored into the local variables `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4):

```
(a, b) = (2, 3)
```

Does not create a tuple, but rather assigns two variables `a` and `b`.

It's equivalent to:

```
a,b = 2,3
```

and sets `a=2` and `b=3` "at the same time". This is useful, for example when switching variables:

```
a,b = b,a
```

which would set `a=3` and `b=2` (and would require a temporary variable if done in sequence).